# Callback in javascript ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a function to handle an ajax request, with a callback.

What this code does is that it sends a request, and writes the response inside a `div` in my html page. 
However i encounter problems with the callback, and i am not sure if the function works properly...

So my question is about the 2 lines of code inside `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` and i have highlighted them.

**Code:**

```
    function check_if_over(callback) {

        //first i collect some variables from the UI
        var val1 = $('#timer').text(),
            val2 = $('#work').val();

        var val5=val1.split(":",1);

        //I initialize the xmlhttp object
        xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

        if (xmlhttp==null)
        {
        alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
        return;
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                //*****my question is about this part inside the "if"

                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {

                        document.getElementById('content0').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                       callback.call(xmlhttp.responseText);

                }
        };
        xmlhttp.open('GET','Controller?action=check&timer='+val5+'&work='+val2);
        xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

So my question is, if the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` works properly like that, performing the task of (a) writing the appropriate code inside my div, and (b) performing the callback.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

So after that i do this thing, and i see that it does my prints in a non-expected way, as it skips the first print on the first iteration of this code, and makes it exactly on the time for the second iteration like that:

> point 2
>
> point 2
>
> (small wait)
>
> point 1

(I am basically alternating between 2 states every 1 minute, so i use this to check asynchronously something in the server-side. So this is where the checking happens.)

```
        check_if_over(function() {
            alert("point 1");
            over = document.getElementById("value_ok").firstChild.nodeValue;
        }
        alert("point 2");
```

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that with jquery it works perfectly,

> point 2
>
> (small wait)
>
> point 1
>
> point 2
>
> (small wait)
>
> etc..

Comment: _“So my question is, if the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange works properly like that, performing the task of (a) writing the appropriate code inside my div, and (b) performing the callback.”_ – I can’t spot a _question_ in that statement.

Comment: what problem do you actually have with the callback? Could you explain further? What's the value of the ajax response? how your callback function is defined?

Comment: i mean if this is an appropriate implementation of those two tasks, because i am not very familiar with the way callback works. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this, or maybe my implementation is error prone, thats what i mean.

Comment: You get no error messages at all? What does the "callback" parameter contain (how is the function check_if_over called?)

Comment: You could just use `callback(xmlhttp.responseText);` I debugged with `.call` giving me `undefined` when printing, but the first mentioned way works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery why not use jQuery's `$.get` function?

```
function check_if_over(callback) {
    //first i collect some variables from the UI
    var val1 = $('#timer').text(),
        val2 = $('#work').val(),
        val5 = val1.split(":",1);

    $.get('Controller?action=check&timer='+val5+'&work='+val2, function(data) {
        $('#content0').html(data);
        callback.call(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: OP didn't mentioned jQuery

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan He's using jQuery selectors

Comment: how do you know is jQuery and not some user defined method or some other library if OP is not using jquery tag? and how this jQuery code should solve his problem?

Comment: I dont know why, but this works. Thanks. If anyone can explain why, I think it would be interesting

Comment: @ge0rgi0 I can't explain why. But as I mentioned in the comment of your post, I tried your code and the variables passed to `callback` was `undefined`, although if I skipped the `.call()` function and called the function normally as `callback(xmlhttp.responseText);` it worked. So you could've solved it that way. Although seeing you are using jQuery there's no reason not to use their implementation instead.